# Why are CRT tv's so long

Tags: electromagnetism, vacuum

I am wondering why a crt is so long.  I understand that they need a vacuum tube that gets electrons shot through it by why does the tube have to be as long as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the beam hitting the monitor also feeds into it. The steeper the angle of impact the more circular the area it lights up. The shallower the angle, the more it light's up an extended ellipse, smearing the picture out near the edges. This all depends on how tightly you can focus the beam, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The further the screen is from the electron gun the easier it is to deflect electrons onto it.
Or to put it the other way, if the screen is too close the magnetic field cannot deflect electrons to the edge of it effectively. It's too great an angle.

Comment: Just getting the bending angle is only part of the problem. Getting the right timing relationship for the bending angle is a big deal if you are using analog electronics (which was the usual case for a long, long time). Between the small angle approximation and a slightly curved screen a long tube can have a nice linear relationship between field strength and displacement from center on the screen which means you can drive the thing with a sawtooth signal. Short tubes need cleverness.

Comment: @dmckee, it sounds like that you've twisted a horizontal and/or vertical linearity pot(s) at some time.  Speaking of clever, have you ever tried to set the purity and convergence on an 'old fashioned' color CRT (or far worse, the registration on a 3-CRT projection TV)?  For those scratching their heads, see, e.g., [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AWG61TAIHg)

Comment: Indeed, and on some of the old CRT green screen oscilloscopes.